# How do I use nickname rather than author name?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When code is run it gives me the user name of the author of the message I would perfer that it use the server nick name. Can this be done

```
@client.command(name='d')
async def dice(context):
    diceEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Rolling for " + str(context.message.author.name), color=0xCC5500)
```

when code is run it gives me the user name of the author of the message I would prefer that it use the server nick name. Can this be done

Comment: You can use `context.author.nick`

Comment: The `.nick` will work as per the comment above, just note that Nickname is defaulted to `None`. So you might want to conditionally use `Name` when `nick` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `context.author.name` or `context.author.nick`, you can use `context.author.display_name` :

```py
@client.command(name='d')
async def dice(context):
    diceEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Rolling for " + str(context.author.display_name), color=0xCC5500)
```

I'd say `context.author.display_name` is better than `context.author.nick` because it will return the member's discord name if he doesn't have any nick on the server.